# If I flip 5 coins, what are the chances of me getting 4 heads and 1 tail?

Tags: probability

If I flip 5 coins, what are the chances of me getting 4 heads and 1 tail? So there is a 50% chance of getting a head, but getting two in a row means they are multiplied. 1/2 x 1/2 x 1/2 x 1/2 = 1/16 this is the probability of 4 heads but i dont know what to do with the tail??? someone pls help

Comment: Have you met the *binomial distribution*?

Comment: hint: probability of a tail, is as the same as probability of a head, they are independent, also the order doesn't matter i assume, so remember there is more than one way to get 4 heads 1 tail, HHHHT or HHHTH for example

Answer (score 1):

If we flip five coins and get one tail, that tail could be the first, second, third, fourth, or fifth coin.

We are *choosing* one coin from five to be a tail, this can be done in $5$ ways.

We roll four of our heads with probability $\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4$, and the selected tail with probability $\displaystyle \frac12$.

Therefore, we have probability $\displaystyle \binom{5}{1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^1$.

Notice the parentheses with two numbers in it say $5$ choose $1$, which is the number of ways to select one object from five.

This is equal to $\boxed{\displaystyle \frac{5}{32}}$.